# Power consumption percentages of notebook (and netbooks) components

Tags: ssd, power-consumption

I see many component manufacturers boast that their products use N% less power than their competitor or older version product, but nobody says how much it matters in comparison to total power consumption. So it isn't clear if a new piece will save a significant portion of a notebook's charge.

What are the approximate consumption percentages for components in notebooks and netbooks?

I am specifically interested in how much power swapping hdd to ssd can save in asus eee pc.

Answer (score 1):

If it's measuring power consumption that you're interested in, then I guess you should read [this entertaining article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/revisiting-how-much-power-does-my-laptop-really-use.html) written by Jeff Atwood himself. He recommends using Kill-a-Watt to measure power consumption.

If you'd rather not spend any money for the purpose, I'd say [Joulemeter](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/fe9e10c5-5c5b-450c-a674-daf55565f794/) is something that might interest you.

If you'd also like to measure core temperatures of your CPU, graphics card and HDD then you can use [Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/support/downloads) or [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com) to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a comparison](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-recommendation-review,3194-7.html) of some ssds and hdds regarding speed an power consumption.

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Comparison_of_SSD_with_hard_disk_drives):

> High performance flash-based SSDs generally require half to a third of
>   the power of HDDs. High-performance DRAM SSDs generally require as
>   much power as HDDs, and must be connected to power even when the rest
>   of the system is shut down.

Here is an article where they measured the total power consumtion based on components [power consumtion based on components](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.5604&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

How much an ssd will save you depends on how you use your pc because power consumption by component varies greatly depending on the use case (p.6 of article).